# Putting stuff in windows

Tags: user-interface, widget, pyside

How can I put stuff in the main window? I want to create a line edit in the main window(beneath the menu bar, maybe with some decription laber in front of it). How is this done? I used grid layout and this box layout, nothing works.
(sry for another trivial question, there are only few tutorials on pyside out there, and most of them only cover how to create single windows with buttons ect.)

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore, QtWebKit


class FirstClass(QtGui.QMainWindow, QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(FirstClass, self).__init__()
        self.startingUI()

    def startingUI(self):

        self.setWindowTitle('Hauptfenster')
        self.resize(800, 400)
        self.statusBar()

        #Menueinstellungen an sich

        menue = self.menuBar()

        #Actions des Menues:
        #datei menue
        menuleiste_datei = menue.addMenu('File')

        datei_exit = QtGui.QAction('Exit', self)
        datei_exit.setStatusTip('Close the programm')
        menuleiste_datei.addAction(datei_exit)
        datei_exit.triggered.connect(self.close)

        #Einstellungen menue
        menuleiste_configurations = menue.addMenu('Configurations')
        configurations_settings = QtGui.QAction('Settings', self)
        configurations_settings.setStatusTip('Configurations(Settings)')
        menuleiste_configurations.addAction(configurations_settings)
        configurations_settings.triggered.connect(self.newwindow)

        self.lineedit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lineedit)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()

    def newwindow(self):
        self.wid = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.wid.resize(250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('NewWindow')
        self.wid.show()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    start = FirstClass()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__== '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe creating a class with a multiple inheritance is recommended best practice. If an attribute is not found in `FirstClass`, then it searches left to right (`QtGui.QMainWindow` to `QtGui.QWidget`). From my perspective, this would turn into a nightmare to support and debug. My guess this is why the self.layout is not working properly.

I made separate classes for `QtGui.QMainWindow` and `QtGui.QWidget`. `FirstWindowClass` sets the central widget as `FirstWidgetClass`. `FirstWidgetClass` has your `QLineEdit` and I went ahead and inserted a label. I changed `QHBoxLayout` to `QGridLayout` to help you understand how it works.

Some tips from my learning experiences with Python and Pyside these past couple months:

1. Remember you can always look at PyQt examples and majority will work directly with PySide modules.
2. I recommend looking over http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/index.html as a lot of the modules have simple examples.
3. For my personal project, a lot of the solutions to my Qt questions were in C++ so do not be afraid to convert it to python.

   ```
   import sys
   from PySide import QtGui, QtCore, QtWebKit

   class FirstWindowClass(QtGui.QMainWindow):
       def __init__(self):
           super(FirstWindowClass, self).__init__()

           self.setWindowTitle('Hauptfenster')
           self.resize(800, 400)
           self.statusBar()

           # Set central widget that expands to fill your window
           self.main_widget = FirstWidgetClass(self)
           self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)

           #Menueinstellungen an sich

           menue = self.menuBar()

           #Actions des Menues:
           #datei menue
           menuleiste_datei = menue.addMenu('File')

           datei_exit = QtGui.QAction('Exit', self)
           datei_exit.setStatusTip('Close the programm')
           menuleiste_datei.addAction(datei_exit)
           datei_exit.triggered.connect(self.close)

           #Einstellungen menue
           menuleiste_configurations = menue.addMenu('Configurations')
           configurations_settings = QtGui.QAction('Settings', self)
           configurations_settings.setStatusTip('Configurations(Settings)')
           menuleiste_configurations.addAction(configurations_settings)
           configurations_settings.triggered.connect(self.newwindow)

           # Open the window
           self.show()

       def newwindow(self):
           self.wid = QtGui.QWidget()
           self.wid.resize(250, 150)
           self.wid.setWindowTitle('NewWindow')
           self.wid.show()


   class FirstWidgetClass(QtGui.QWidget):
       def __init__(self, parent=None):
           super(FirstWidgetClass, self).__init__()

           self.label_example = QtGui.QLabel('Enter Data:')

           self.lineedit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
           self.layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
           self.layout.addWidget(self.label_example, 0, 0)
           self.layout.addWidget(self.lineedit, 0, 1)
           self.setLayout(self.layout)
           self.show()


   def main():

       app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
       start = FirstWindowClass()
       sys.exit(app.exec_())

   if __name__== '__main__':
       main()
   ```